# Hive: Inner Join query executing forever due to last Reducer job

Tags: hadoop, join, hive, hiveql, azure-hdinsight

Using Hive 1.2.1000.2 on Azure HDInsight 3.6 performing an `INNER JOIN` to get the count of records that are present both in `Table_1` and `Table_2`.

Details of the tables:

**Table_1**: 310M records

Sample data:

```
master_id        modelkey     order_id  
---------------------------------------
mi0000bd1444     4874         d988e53cd
mi000097d5       44365        p0905gd44
mi0000d2ab09ea   309141         
mi0001d6a        8705         7574  
mi00011f7c085    4063         d165804b2
mi0001a57db      314          9c84ft879
```

**Table_2**: 35M records

Sample data:

```
order_id    vendor_id
---------------------------------------
81d162f23   7122a0c
6988e53cd   517ba6e
5165804b2   5c5e161
47ba91ea3   7686b2d
f45cab9de   35be1af
```

Below are the details of what I've tried so far.

Hive query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM db.table_1 t1
INNER JOIN db.table_2 t2 ON t1.order_id = t2.order_id;
```

Hive properties:

```
SET hive.tez.container.size=10240;
SET tez.am.resource.memory.mb=10240;
SET tez.task.resource.memory.mb=10240;
SET hive.execution.engine=tez;
SET hive.exec.compress.output=true;
SET hive.vectorized.execution.enabled = true;
SET hive.vectorized.execution.reduce.enabled = true;
SET hive.optimize.skewjoin=true;
SET hive.skewjoin.key=100000;
```

The query is executing for >7 hours and getting stuck at the last Reducer job .e.

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    VERTICES      STATUS  TOTAL  COMPLETED  RUNNING  PENDING  FAILED  KILLED
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Map 1 ..........   SUCCEEDED      1          1        0        0       0       0
Map 4 ..........   SUCCEEDED    715        715        0        0       0       0
Reducer 2 .....      RUNNING    189        188        1        0       0       0
Reducer 3            RUNNING      1          0        1        0       0       0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
VERTICES: 02/04  [=========================>>-] 99%   ELAPSED TIME: 25307.97 s  
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Is there a way to overcome the last Reducer's issue and, get the result?

Explain for:

1. [table_1](http://www.filedropper.com/table1)
2. [table_2](http://www.filedropper.com/table2)
3. [table1_table2_join](http://www.filedropper.com/table1table2join)

Comment: Please provide EXPLAIN command output. It will show what each vertex is doing. I guess Reducer 2  is doing common join operator. Also check for skew: select count(*) cnt, order_id from db.table_1 group by order_id having count(*)>1 order by cnt desc limit 10; Do the same for both tables and provide the results please. Though 188 slow running reducers does not look like a skew. maybe not enough parallelism

Comment: @leftjoin Have updated the question with the results. Please suggest.

Comment: @leftjoin No worries. Updated the question with the results of EXPLAIN. Please have a look.

Comment: Links do not open. Need counts for top 10 keys from both tables which I asked before and EXPLAIN plan for the whole query

Comment: counts are very important, please provide at least them. No links/pictures please. I could not open links you posted.

Comment: @leftjoin Thanks for your time and inputs. Was able to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Performed the following steps, it helped! and hope it help others:

1. Removed the records which had no value i.e. `order_id=''`
2. Performed the JOIN in batches rather than doing all in one go
3. Referred the below for setting certain hive properties:

[hive properties](https://www.justanalytics.com/blog/technical-know-how/hive-tez-query-optimization)